# why are my questions not displayed on the Dom and shows error as function not defined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I don't understand what the error is because my question and options are not being displayed for a quiz and show a very unexceptional error as (Uncaught ReferenceError: loadQuiz is not defined).
My quiz only Displays :

> QUESTION 
> option a
> option b 
> option c
> option d

But I have also mentioned exact questions and options in the array. why are they not being displayed?

```js
let quizData = [{
    question: 'A disk where number of sectors are fixed is called',
    a: 'CD',
    b: "Floppy",
    c: " Soft sectored",
    d: "Hard sectored",
    correct: 'Hard sectored'
  },
  {
    question: 'A disk where number of sectors are fixed is called',
    a: 'CD',
    b: "Floppy",
    c: " Soft sectored",
    d: "Hard sectored",
    correct: 'Hard sectored'
  },
  {
    question: 'A disk where number of sectors are fixed is called',
    a: 'CD',
    b: "Floppy",
    c: " Soft sectored",
    d: "Hard sectored",
    correct: 'Hard sectored'
  },
  {
    question: 'A disk where number of sectors are fixed is called',
    a: 'CD',
    b: "Floppy",
    c: " Soft sectored",
    d: "Hard sectored",
    correct: 'Hard sectored'
  }

]

let quiz = document.getElementById('quizdiv')
let question = document.getElementsByClassName('question')
let anyanswer = document.getElementById('answer')
let op1 = document.getElementById('a_value')
let op2 = document.getElementById('b_value')
let op3 = document.getElementById('c_value')
let op4 = document.getElementById('d_value')
let submit = document.getElementById('btn')

let currentquestion = 0
let quizscore = 0


loadQuiz()

loadQuiz = () => {
  deselect()

  question.innerHTML = quizData[currentquestion].question
  op1.innerHTML = quizData[currentquestion].a
  op2.innerHTML = quizData[currentquestion].b
  op3.innerHTML = quizData[currentquestion].c
  op4.innerHTML = quizData[currentquestion].d
}

deselect = () => {
  anyanswer.forEach(anyanswer => anyanswer.checked = false)

}

submit.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let selectedoption
  anyanswer.forEach(anyanswer => {
    if (anyanswer.checked) {
      selectedoption = anyanswer.value

    }
  })
  if (selectedoption = quizData[currentquestion].correct) {
    quizscore = +1
  }
  currentquestion = +1
  loadQuiz();
})
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-7  shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
      <h1 class="js text-center">js quiz</h1>
      <div id="quizdiv">
        <h2 id="question">Question</h2>
        <li> <input type="radio" class="answer" value="a" name="option">
          <label form="a" id="a_value">option a</label>
        </li>

        <li> <input type="radio" class="answer" value="b" name="option">
          <label form="b" id="b_value">option b</label>
        </li>

        <li> <input type="radio" class="answer" value="c" name="option">
          <label form="c" id="c_value">option c</label>
        </li>

        <li> <input type="radio" class="answer" value="d" name="option">
          <label form="d" id="d_value">option d</label>
        </li>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Aside from Quentin's point, remember that you must declare variables. Right now your code is falling prey to what I call [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You never declare the `loadQuiz` variable. Use `let` or `const` to do so (or use a function declaration instead, which would also have the advantage of being hoisted).

Comment: You're also calling `getElementById` for the answers but these are classes.

Answer (score 2):

The order you do things in matters.

You attempt to define `loadQuiz` on the line **after** you try to call it.

---

‍: Load the quiz.

: Do what now? *bzzt! bzzt! !*

‍: When I tell you to "load the quiz" … are you still listening to me?

---

Reverse the order of those statements.

---

Another solution would be to use `function loadQuiz () {` instead of `loadQuiz = () => {`, as function declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) (i.e. you can write their definition below their use and they will still work).